# How to pass more than id and name through laravel's lists()

Tags: php, laravel, drop-down-menu

I need to pass more than "name" and "id" to select box. 
my model has id, name and price.

So I pass it to the view as:

```
$parts = Part::all()->lists('name','id);
```

I'd like to have select box options like:

```
<option value='id' data-price='price'>name</option>
```

My guess is try to pass array as first parameter in lists() method, but then I don't know is there way to use Form helper.

```
 $parts = Part::all()->lists('["name"=>name, "price"=>price]','id');
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lists()` is not for building a select, it just creates an array out of a collection. You have to pass the full model to the view and then build the select manually:

```
<select name="part">
    @foreach($parts as $part)
        <option value="{{ $part->id }}" data-price="{{ $part->price }}">
            {{ $part->name }}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to do something like

```
$parts = Part::all()->get(array('id', 'name', 'price'))->toArray();
```

that should give you only the wanted columns in an associative array :)